# initializing a structure array in c with #define

Tags: c, gcc, struct

The following code gives me this warning:

```
tag_info.h:17: warning: missing braces around initializer
tag_info.h:17: warning: (near initialization for âtag_list_data[0].subtagsâ)
```

I have tried alot of things but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone please suggest something

```
typedef struct Attr{    
            char attr_name[64];             
            value_type_t value;             
            int mandatory;                  
}Attr_t;

typedef struct Tags {
        unsigned int tag_id;           
        Attr_t *attr_list;              
        char *tag_name;                
        int tag_type;                   
        int subtags[html_subtag_num];   
}Tags_t;

Tags_t tag_list_data[150] = {
        #include "tag_info.h"
        {0,0,0,0,0}
};

where the "tag_info.h" contains :
#if defined(TAG_DEFINE)
      #undef TAG_DEFINE
#else
      #define TAG_DEFINE(a,b,c,...) {.tag_id=a, .tag_name=#b, .tag_type=c, ##__VA_ARGS__}
#endif

TAG_DEFINE(0,TAG_NONE,0,0),
TAG_DEFINE(1,!--,0,0),
TAG_DEFINE(2,!doctype,0,0),
TAG_DEFINE(3,a, 1, 1, 117, 59,11,118,92,100),
```

Comment: Have you tried putting bracers around the value(s) for `subtags`?

Comment: What is the contents of `tag_info.h`?

Comment: If it consists of something like `{a,b,c},{d,e,f}` then make sure, that you have a *comma* at the very end (or in the .c file just before `{0,0,..}`)

Comment: Silly me, all this info is already in the post!

Comment: This code compiles for me given that html_subtag_num is a macro expanding to a big enough number.

Comment: I suggest using gcc -E to see what the substitutions are, adding some line breaks to make it readable and ensure error message line numbers are helpful, hacking it around until you have working code, then modifying the defines again to generate the same.  Trying to cope with both macros and fiddly code at the same time just makes it harder to follow the error messages.  (BTW - if you conditionally `#undef` TAG_DEFINE you then don't set it`, you want `#ifdef` / `#undef` / `#endif` / `#define`...)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Yes, i have tried doing that but then it is giving me a different set of errors, essentially i am looking for a way to put an array here but since that is not possible with a #define, i decided on using ##__VA_ARGS__ which allows for variable number of arguments,which makes up my array subtag_list

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk : have #defined html_tag_num as 150,  can you give me the exact gcc command you are using for compilation, as far as i have found, it has to be do with a certain gcc bug.Thanks :)

Comment: Hm, I just used `gcc aa.c -c` but now I see that with `-Wall` it gives that message as a warning, sorry, I thought you meant getting an error:)

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `subtags` as if it were multiple members of the `Tags` struct:

```
typedef struct Tags {
    ...
    int subtags_0;
    int subtags_1;
    int subtags_2;
} Tags_t;

Tags_t t = { ..., 0, 1, 2 };
```

But it is an array. Thus you should initialize it as a single entity.

```
typedef struct Tags {
    ...
    int subtags[html_subtag_num];
} Tags_t;

Tags_t t = { .tag_id = 0, ..., { 0, 1, 2 } };
// or 
Tags_t t = { .tag_id = 0, ..., .subtags = { 0, 1, 2 } };
```

Also, you don't need to use concatenation (`##`)

```
 #define TAG_DEFINE(a,b,c,...) { ..., ## __VA_ARGS__}
```

In the end, it should look like

```
 #define TAG_DEFINE(a,b,c,...) { ..., .subtags = { __VA_ARGS__ } }
 ...
 Tags_t tag_list_data[150] = {
     ...
     { 0,0,0,0,{0}}
 }
```

instead of

```
#define TAG_DEFINE(a,b,c,...) { ..., ##__VA_ARGS__}
...
Tags_t tag_list_data[150] = {
   ...
   { 0,0,0,0,0 }
}
```